# optaplanner Matrix benchmarking failed Caused by:Unmarshalling of benchmarkConfigResource fails on line number (40)

Tags: optaplanner, xstream

I have successed use the benchmark without Template-based benchmarking before, but the Template-based benchmarkin can not work here.
I use the test case in https://docs.optaplanner.org/

```
<plannerBenchmark>
  <benchmarkDirectory>local/data</benchmarkDirectory>
  <parallelBenchmarkCount>(availableProcessorCount / 2)+1</parallelBenchmarkCount>
  <warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>60</warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>
  <inheritedSolverBenchmark>
    ...
  </inheritedSolverBenchmark>

<#list [5, 7, 11, 13] as entityTabuSize>
<#list [500, 1000, 2000] as acceptedCountLimit>
  <solverBenchmark>
    <name>Tabu Search entityTabuSize ${entityTabuSize} acceptedCountLimit ${acceptedCountLimit}</name>
    <solver>
      <localSearch>
        <unionMoveSelector>
          <changeMoveSelector/>
          <swapMoveSelector/>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <acceptor>
          <entityTabuSize>${entityTabuSize}</entityTabuSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
          <acceptedCountLimit>${acceptedCountLimit}</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
      </localSearch>
    </solver>
  </solverBenchmark>
</#list>
</#list>
</plannerBenchmark>
```

It seems like there is a problem in

```
<#list [5, 7, 11, 13] as entityTabuSize>
```

the optaPlanner version is 7.43.0
the xstream version is 1.4.14

there are sonme error information

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       : 
class               : org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig
required-type       : org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 40
version             : 1.4.14
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1404)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1383)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1268)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlReader(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:228)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlInputStream(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:204)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.config.PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlResource(PlannerBenchmarkConfig.java:140)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: 
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:124)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:148)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.hasMoreChildren(AbstractPullReader.java:87)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:329)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected character in markup # (position: END_TAG seen ...</inheritedSolverBenchmark>\r\n\r\n\r\n<#... @40:3) 
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1261)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:109)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: It is becauese I didn't use FreeMarker?

Answer (score 1):

According to the stacktrace, you are using `PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromXmlResource()`, which can be used to read benchmark configuration XML, but not the FreeMarker template.
To read the benchmark configuration FreeMarker template, use one of the `PlannerBenchmarkConfig.createFromFreemarkerXmlResource()` methods.
See [Template-based benchmarking](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#templateBasedBenchmarking) for more details.